# GCS Ingress & Egress Charges from App Engine Instances

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

If I create an application on Google App Engine, would I incur ingress and egress charges on data transferred to and from Google Cloud Storage through by my app instances?

The documentation seemed to suggest that such charges are not incurred when using the GCS client library. However, I'd like to use Go on App Engine. As far as I can tell, there is no GCS client library for Go so I would be using the Cloud Storage REST API.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will not be charged. You will be going through the `urlfetch` interface, which if used with a Google Cloud Storage URL does not incur bandwidth charges.

Comment: Can you explain that setup?  I've tried using GAE to download an image from an origin CMS, save it in GCS (using `cloudstorage.open()`), and then have the GAE app make a URL that a client can call, and doing all that with the intent of not using GAE bandwidth to serve the image, rather GCS egress... and I'm not having any success.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is no longer correct. GCP changes protocol such that egress charges from GCS are only waived if the serving bucket and client instance reside in the same region. Multiregional buckets always have egress charges ($0.12/GB I believe)