# GCS billing of network egress from default bucket

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

We use GCS as storage for our App engine application. All data are stored in default bucket for GAE application. Stats logs show average egress about 50 GB per day. So it can be about 1.5TB per month. But I can not see any charges for network egress in monthly invoice for my billing account. Has the default bucket any influence how is computed the billing for GAE / GCS ?

It’s seems that egress through GAE app instance [is not charged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17733395/gcs-ingress-egress-charges-from-app-engine-instances). But in my case is situation different.  GAE prepare signed URL for  downloading of GCS object > URL is send back to the client and client uses URL for downloading.

Thanks

Comment: 50GB per day or 50MB per day? 50GB/day does not match 1.5GB/month.

Comment: Yeah, either you mean 50 MiB/day or 1.5 TiB/day. I'm guessing it's the former?

Comment: Sorry fixed. It is 1.5 TB / month

Answer (score 0):

The only thing the default bucket does is that it gives you some free storage that your other buckets don't have.

For the rest, there is no difference at all, so if you give your customers a download URL and make them download from your bucket, then yes that kind of network egress is normal.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it. Strange that Google doesn't charge this egress.

Comment: @voldy what do you mean? If it's the egress to an app engine, it makes sense, since it's staying within Google's infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't charge for egress as long as the data transfer is happening between google cloud services in the same region, like between GCS and GAE.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing